# A question concerning a right $A/\operatorname{rad}A$-module.

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Let $\DeclareMathOperator\Top{top}\DeclareMathOperator\Rad{rad}M$ be a right $A$-module, let $\Top M=M/\Rad M$.

We see that, if $e$ is a primitive idempotent in $A$, then $eA$ is a indecomposable module in $A_A$.

Let $B=A/\Rad A$, then $\Top eA=eA/\Rad eA=eA/e\Rad A$ can be seen as a right $B$-module (Since $eA\cdot \Rad A\subset e\Rad A$).

Let $\bar{e}=e+\Rad A\in B$, then what confused me is why $\Top eA\cong\bar{e}B$?

Thanks to everyone!

Comment: Do we know anything about $A$?

Comment: $K$ is an algebraically closed field and that
$A$ is a finite dimensional $K$-algebra..

Answer (score 1):

You can define a natural map $\alpha: top\ eA \rightarrow \overline{e}B$ by the form $\alpha(\overline{ea})= e \overline{a}$, and it's easy to check it is an isomorphism.

Comment: To ensure this map is well defined, we need $\mathrm{rad}(eA) \subseteq e \cdot \mathrm{rad}(A)$. Is that really true in general?

Comment: Dou you know the fact $M rad A=rad M$?

Comment: That does not hold for any ring. That's why I asked what do we know about $A$.

Comment: In this question, $A$ is a K-algebra, M is a right A-module. By the above fact, we get $rad eA=erad A$.

Comment: I agree if $A$ is semilocal. But I am not sure about $\mathrm{rad}(eA) = e \cdot \mathrm{rad}(A)$ in general. Can you give a proof or a reference?

Comment: It is true. Since $A = eA \oplus (1-e)A$ we have $\mathrm{rad}(A) = \mathrm{rad}(eA) \oplus \mathrm{rad}((1-e)A)$. Multiplying both sides by $e$ from the left yields $e \cdot \mathrm{rad}(A) = \mathrm{rad}(eA)$.

Comment: If $A$ is a ring, by the Corollary 15.18 on page 171 of the book "Rings and categories of modules", it seems that $e\ rad A \subseteq rad\  eA$?

Comment: By Theorem 24.7 [Lam - a first course in noncommutative rings], for any projective module $P$ we have $\mathrm{rad}(P) = P \, \mathrm{rad}(A) \subsetneq P$.

Comment: Thank you!!   I see you write $\alpha(\overline{ea})= e \overline{a}\in\bar{e}B$..  I think $\alpha(\overline{ea})=\alpha(ea+e radA)=e\bar{a}=e(a+radA)=ea+e radA$,  I wonder why $ea+e radA\in \bar{e}B=(e+radA)(A+radA)=ea+radA$?.

Comment: $radA$ is a two-sided ideal, you can look it at this book "elements of the representation thoery of assocaitive algebras, volume 1" at page 5

Comment: I know $radA$  is a two-sided ideal, I wonder why $ea+eradA\in\bar{e}B=ea+radA$.....Since $ea+eradA$ and $ea+radA$ are different coset.....